# Having trouble updating Android RecyclerView with new ArrayList

Tags: android

I have a question regarding `RecyclerView`.

The app I am working on has set of time lists with available times. Whenever I send a `GET` request to server, it returns a response with available times. Then I make a new `ArrayList` and make a new Adapter with this list to update the `RecyclerView`. But the `RecyclerView` seems not to be updating with new time list.

This same approach worked with a `ListView` before. Does anyone know how to update the `RecyclerView` with a new ArrayList?

Comment: Please consider adding some sample code. : )

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new adapter. You can create a method (something like `updateDataSet(ArrayList<Date> times)`) in your adapter-class. In this method exchange the old times with the new times and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

If you need further info please post some code!